# Error adding reference "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll" to Windows Metro Style Application

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I add a reference `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0` to my `Windows Metro` Style App. Set `Copy Local = true`, but when I try to build this project, got an error:

**Error 1** `Invalid Resx file. This .resources file should not be read with this reader. The resource reader type is "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.GzipResourceReader, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll TFS Project Management`

I can not set `copy local = false` in `Windows Metro` Style app, because this `DLL` not copied to app package (I gon a runtime error: `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`)

`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll` works fine, the problem is only with `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client`.

The same situation when I add `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll` from `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a`

How can I resolve the problem ?
Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the TFS SDK for Metro applications because the .Net Framework dependencies that the TFS SDK requires are not available in Metro applications.